# Conflicting mismatched tags compile with standard library but not otherwise

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, tuples

I was taking a look at how `std::tuple_size` is defined in the standard library on my system.  I have a Mac OS, and the compiler version is `Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)`.  The standard library is found in the `InstalledDir` location as outputted by `g++ --version`

Given that the following code does not compile (because `clang` does not like specializing/re-declaring something as a `struct` that was previously defined as a `class` and vice versa)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <class T>
class Something;
template <class One, class Two>
struct Something<std::pair<One, Two>>;
template <class One, class Two>
class Something<std::pair<One, Two>>
    : public std::integral_constant<int, 2> {};

int main() {
  cout << std::tuple_size<std::array<int, 2>>::value << endl;
  cout << std::tuple_size<std::tuple<int, int>>::value << endl;
  cout << std::tuple_size<std::pair<int, int>>::value << endl;
}
```

with the following error

```
error: struct template 'Something' was previously declared as a class template [-Werror,-Wmismatched-tags]
struct Something<std::pair<One, Two>>;
^
test.cpp:49:7: note: previous use is here
class Something;
```

I saw the following code in the standard library header `<array>` (with the specialized definition of `tuple_size` as a `class` following later on)

```
template <class T> class tuple_size;
template <size_t I, class T> class tuple_element;
template <class T1, class T2> struct tuple_size<pair<T1, T2> >;
```

How does this compile when used in the above code after removing the definition and declarations for `Something`?  Shouldn't the above code raise warnings about `tuple_size` being defined or declared twice once as a `class` and another as a `struct`?

Comment: Maybe it would be good to add the context of your question. I saw your previous questions today (which you've probably deleted as I can't see them now) and find the current question legit. However without that context the question might be perceived as kind of incomplete...

Comment: @W.F. I deleted them because I didn't want to get into arguments explaining myself.  People did not seem to like the context and thought that it was out of scope.  I can't duplicate the environment of my work infrastructure, so I've narrowed the question to what I think is happening in the standard library there and what I don't understand.

Comment: OK, a little more emphasis on the struct/class problem could make the question a little bit more clear I think...

Comment: @AndyG yes I did, trying to mirror what I see in the standard library as I mentioned in the question

Comment: @W.F. looks better?

Comment: @AndyG The third thing is the declaration of the specialization

Comment: @AndyG how are they not real analogues?  Both are a non specialized declaration of the template followed by a specialized declaration and then a definition of the specialization

Answer (score 2):

> Given that the following code does not compile (because clang does not like specializing/re-declaring something as a struct that was previously defined as a class and vice versa)

clang is fine with that.

> with the following error
>
> ```
> error: struct template 'Something' was previously declared as a class template [-Werror,-Wmismatched-tags]
> ```

This shows that a) you enabled a warning that isn't enabled by default, namely `-Wmismatched-tags`, and b) you requested to treat warnings as errors.

This warning exists for compatibility with another compiler. C++ is fine with mismatched tags, so are all conforming implementations, so is clang. You shouldn't be enabling this warning unless you have a very good reason.

Warnings generally do not affect system headers, even warnings that would otherwise be treated as errors, that's why it worked in there, but your own code isn't a system header and isn't and shouldn't be granted the same exceptions.

Comment: Ok, so let's say the system header itself doesn't cause problems because it's marked with a special whatever.  But then what happens with client code?  How does that compile even though the system header contains the double declaration?  Does the compiler still take care of that?

Comment: `C++ is fine with mismatched tags`, could you give a quote from the standard or cppreference to go with that?

Comment: @Curious Sorry, but I don't think that's fair. You trusted your compiler when you thought it told you that was invalid, I gave enough details for you to get your compiler to tell you it is in fact valid. Anyway, the standard covers it in [dcl.type.elab]p3.

Comment: @Curious I meant I think it's unfair that you ask for more proof that it's valid than what you accepted initially to conclude that it's invalid.

Comment: Sorry if I was unfair in asking for a reference :(  I just wanted something to go off of from the standard itself...

Comment: @Curious Yeah, I did mention [dcl.type.elab]p3. It says `union` must be used to refer to a union, and `class` or `struct` to refer to a class defined using the `class` or `struct` keyword. Without including "respectively", that means either can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose thay `<array>` compile thanks the

```
#pragma GCC system_header
```

that you can find in it (or, at least, in my version of the header).

Try writing the following header ("something.h")

```
#ifndef _something_h_
#define _something_h_

//#pragma GCC system_header

template <class T>
class Something;

template <class One, class Two>
struct Something<std::pair<One, Two>>;

template <class One, class Two>
class Something<std::pair<One, Two>>
 {};

#endif /* ndef _something_h_ */
```

and modify the main cpp file as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

#include "something.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
  cout << std::tuple_size<std::array<int, 2>>::value << endl;
  cout << std::tuple_size<std::tuple<int, int>>::value << endl;
  cout << std::tuple_size<std::pair<int, int>>::value << endl;
}
```

With the pragma line commented, you should get the same error.

Uncomment the pragma line in "something.h" and should compile without problem.